# averaging members of a group in oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, aggregate, average

I'm working on a query to show general usage of our server over the week. More specifically, I'm trying to find the average number of requests during a given hour on a given day of the week. I know the average function is there, but trying to average only the members of each group is proving troublesome. When I run this query:

```
SELECT DOW, HH24, AVG(LISTAGG(SV_REQUESTS) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SV_REQUESTS))
  FROM
    (SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS SV_REQUESTS,  
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM') AS MM,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD') AS DD,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24') AS HH24,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'D-DAY') AS DOW
    FROM ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR
    WHERE TIMESTAMP > to_date('01-08-2015','DD-MM-YYYY')
    GROUP BY
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'D-DAY'))
GROUP BY DOW, HH24;
```

I get:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can anyone help? Do I need another subquery to do this properly?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `listagg`?  Why don't you just want `avg(sv_requests)`?  Can you post some sample data, show what `avg(sv_requests)` returns and tell us what result you want instead (and why)?

Comment: @JustinCave you're totally right, just using `avg(sv_requests)` fixed it. I was confused by the oracle documentation. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just want `avg(sv_requests)`.  Aggregate functions (such as `avg` or `count`) inherently operate on the groups of rows that you are grouping by.  So for each distinct combination of `DOW` and `HH24`, the `sv_requests` for the corresponding rows will be averaged.

```
SELECT DOW, HH24, AVG(SV_REQUESTS)
  FROM
    (SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS SV_REQUESTS,  
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM') AS MM,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD') AS DD,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24') AS HH24,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'D-DAY') AS DOW
    FROM ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR
    WHERE TIMESTAMP > to_date('01-08-2015','DD-MM-YYYY')
    GROUP BY
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'MM'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD'),
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'D-DAY'))
GROUP BY DOW, HH24;
```